# Insufficient access when trying to set machine OS attributes when joining Linux server to Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, domain, adsi

I am trying to join a Linux server to Active Directory. I want to set OS Name and OS Version attributes upon joining the domain using this command:

```
/usr/bin/net ads join -k -S adserver.example.local osName=CentOS osVer=6.5
```

I've delegated permissions to a bind account so that it can read/write to OS Name and OS Version properties for computer objects. When I try to join domain, I am hit with this error:

```
Failed to join domain: failed to set machine os attributes: Insufficient access
```

I have no issues joining the domain when leaving off osName and osVer. Just to verify that this account has the right permissions, I manually set these two properties on the computer objects using ADSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From packet analysis, learned that the account being used to join the domain was missing permissions to read/write to Operating System Service Pack. That attribute was automatically being set to the version of samba that was installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually easier to pre-stage the computer account, and assign permissions/owner to the account that will be joining it to the domain.

Comment: I've automated the process from the Linux side and what you described sounds a lot more complicated than what is currently working.

Comment: From a security perspective, it's safer to have a separate computer account prestage process/web service than using a shared provisioning account with elevated permissions in the domain/forest that probably has the credentials saved in a config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and it turned out that there are more permissions required to join a Linux system than a Windows system to the domain.

I added additional permissions to my domain join account following this guide: https://www.computertechblog.com/active-directory-permissions-required-to-join-linux-and-windows-computers-to-a-domain/

**From the above link:**

#### Standard permissions required to join systems to AD (Linux and Windows)

- Reset password
- Read and write account restrictions
- Validated write to DNS host name
- Validated write to service principal name
- Read and write DNS host name attributes

#### Additional permissions required by Linux machines to join AD (Linux)

- Read dNSHostName
- Write dNSHostName
- Read msDS-AddtionalSamAccountName
- Write msDS-AddtionalSamAccountName
- Read msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes
- Write msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes
- Read Operating System
- Write Operating System
- Read Operating System Version
- Write Operating System Version
- Read OperatingSystemServicePack
- Write OperatingSystemServicePack
- Read servicePrincipalName
- Write servicePrincipalName
- Read userAccountControl
- Write userAccountControl
- Read userPrincipal Name
- Write userPrincipal Name

**NOTE:** You must show "Property-specific" permissions to see these extra permissions.

#### Related:

- [Unable to join Ubuntu/Linux to Active Directory as domain-user. Works with Windows clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/1006265/unable-to-join-ubuntu-linux-to-active-directory-as-domain-user-works-with-windo)
- [Unable to join domain using samba tool net or realm/sssd](https://serverfault.com/questions/738802/unable-to-join-domain-using-samba-tool-net-or-realm-sssd)
- [Account to read AD, join machine to domain, delete computer accounts and move computers to OUs](https://serverfault.com/questions/145160/account-to-read-ad-join-machine-to-domain-delete-computer-accounts-and-move-co)